# Navigate to open files / open tabs

Tags: visual-studio, resharper

**Problem:** Some times I have many tabs open and finding a tab is not easy and fast.

**Question:** Is there any shortcut in visual studio or resharper that allow us to find a tab by typing part of file/tab name?

**Example:** Something like `Navigate-> Recent files...` of resharper:

[image: navigate to recent files]

Answer (score 1):

Looking up the [ReSharper 2017.2 Help - Navigation and Search](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Navigation_and_Search__Index.html) I could not find any hint about navigating through active files.

---

Visual Studio allows you to navigate through all open tabs by  using <kbd>Ctrl + Tab</kbd>. This allows you to switch trough all open tabs ordered by their latest use. Use <kbd>Ctrl + Tab</kbd> again for forward and <kbd>Ctrl + Shift + Tab</kbd> for backward navigation. But as you already mentioned with a lots of open tabs it could be slow stepping through all active files.

---

What I personally do in your situation, when trying to find a open tab or any kind of class/file/member, is to use the <kbd>Ctrl + T</kbd> shortcut. This opens the *[Go to Everything/Type …](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Navigation_and_Search__Go_to_Type.html)* popup, which allows you to search for anything within you solution.

> **To find an item in your solution by the item's name**
>
> 1. To use the unified access to all search results, press Ctrl+T to display a pop-up where you can start typing and find everything in your solution that matches your input.
> 2. If you want to limit your search to types (classes, interfaces, structs or enums), press Ctrl+T twice.
> 3. If you want to find anything by a plain textual match, press Ctrl+T three times.
> 4. If you want to search symbols (types, methods, properties, fields, and so on) - press Shift+Alt+T.
> 5. You can also limit the search to files in your solution by pressing Ctrl+Shift+T.
>
> *from [ReSharper Help - Navigation by Name](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Navigation_and_Search__Search.html)*

---

*More Shortcuts: [Resharper - Default Keyboard Shortcut Schemes](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Reference__Keyboard_Shortcuts.html)*

Comment: I was looking for a command that only shows list of tabs to easily find a tab but **Ctrl+T** shows long list of every thing. **Ctrl + Tab** also doesn't allow search and isn't sort tabs list alphabetically. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @ImanMahmoudinasab: In your Question you mentiond the recent file list. As an alternative to the full list, you can use __Strg + ,__ to call it. But this is also only a partial solution.

Answer (score 1):

Yoy can try set shortcut to open window with active tabs: **Options -> KeyBoard -> Window.Windows**

[It will look something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jGnEz.png)